# A question regarding the verb --- would like+ to-infinitive

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, modal-verbs, syntax

I appreciate if someone can help me in clarifying my doubt.

```
I(subj) + would (modal verb)+ like(verb) + to eat (main verb (to-infinitive))+ rice (obj)
```

Are the classes correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[WOULD | Grammar | EnglishClub](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-modal-would.htm):
Would is an auxiliary verb - a modal auxiliary verb.

"I would like to eat rice."

"I" is the subject.

"would like" is the verb phrase

"like" is the verb, and "would" is the auxiliary verb.

See [grammar terms](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_g&page=9FJFuU_dyzUI.html):

> verb
>
> Expresses an action (break, call, tremble, skate), an occurrence
>   (happen, occur) or a state of being (appear, become, seem). **Auxiliary**
>   (or helping) verbs are placed in front of a main verb to form a verb
>   phrase. They have several functions; for example, they may help to
>   create a different tense (e.g. will and be in the verb phrase will be
>   going) or add an idea (e.g. the idea of obligation expressed by must
>   in the verb phrase must go).
>
> verb phrase
>
> Consists of a verb and its auxiliaries. A verb phrase may also act as
>   a predicate. For example, *can swim* is a verb phrase made up of the
>   verb *swim* and its auxiliary *can*. This verb phrase also functions as
>   the predicate in the sentence *Rajiv can swim*.

"would like to eat rice" is the predicate, see [grammar terms](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_g&page=9FJFuU_dyzUI.html):

> predicate
>
> Makes a statement about the subject. The predicate consists of the
>   verb and its objects, complements and modifiers. For example, *handed
>   in my application for the job* is the predicate of the sentence *I
>   handed in my application for the job*.

If the sentence is something like "Rice is what I would like to eat", then "to eat" is the complement of the word "like", see [Infinitive - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive#English):

> As **complements** of other verbs.
>
> The bare infinitive form is a complement of the dummy auxiliary *do*,
>   most modal auxiliary verbs, verbs of perception like *see*, *watch*
>   and *hear* (after a direct object), and the verbs of permission or
>   causation *make*, *bid*, *let*, and *have* (also after a direct
>   object).
>
> The **to-infinitive** is used after many intransitive verbs like
>   *want*, *aim*, ***like***, *fail*, etc., and like a second complement after a direct object in the case of verbs like *want*, *convince*,
>   *aim*, etc.

"to eat rice" is a subordinate clause. See [Definition and Examples of Infinitive Clauses](https://www.thoughtco.com/infinitive-clause-grammar-1691062):

> In English grammar, an infinitive clause is a subordinate clause whose
>   verb is in the infinitive form. Also known as an infinitival clause or
>   a to-infinitive clause
>
> The infinitive clause is called a clause because it may contain such
>   clausal elements as a subject, object, complement, or modifier. Unlike
>   most other subordinate clauses in English, infinitive clauses are not
>   introduced by a subordinating conjunction.

And the whole clause is the direct object of like:

> And in the following examples, the whole infinitive clause [again in
>   bold] is understood as the direct object of hates, loves and expected.
>
> - Jim hates to wash his car.
> - Rosie loves to plan parties.
> - Phil expected Martha to stay at home all day.